# Get value from hidden field - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<input type="hidden" class="Key" value="1m2.123.mds.34g" />`

How can I get the value without using jQuery?

With jQuery i just only write:

```
var parse = $('.Key').attr("value")
alert(parse);
```

I need this in pure JavaScript, maybe use RegEx? I will execute this script on txt file which will contain such line.

Comment: Try document.querySelector('.key').textContent;

Answer (score 1):

check this

```js
window.onload=function(){
  var hidden=document.getElementsByClassName("Key");
  alert(hidden[0].value);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="Key" value="1m2.123.mds.34g" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy! Just use **getElementsByClassName**. E.g:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Key')[0].value
```

Or if you had to get the value by id you can use **getElementById**

```
document.getElementById('idHere').value
```

Comment: What do you mean it won't work on txt file? Do you want to read a text file and find the line that has `<input type='hidden' value='xoxo' />`? You haven't made it very clear. @Pino77

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array of HTML elements, so that line won't work.

Comment: @James111 Yes, exactly!

Comment: Of course it'll work `[0]` references the first item in an HTMLCollection.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputs = getElementsByClassName('Key');
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) {
        console.log(inputs[i].value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's 4 ways to get the value of `.Key`. Also I added a better way to do it in jQuery as well using the method `val()`.

#### SNIPPET

```js
var k = document.querySelector('.Key').value;
console.log(k);

// This works if .Key is inside a <form>
var e = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
console.log(e);

var y = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
console.log(y);

var s = document.getElementsByClassName('Key')[0].value;
console.log(s);

//BTW there's a better way of finding value with jQuery
var $Key = $('.Key').val();
console.log($Key);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='f1'>
  <input type="hidden" class="Key" value="1m2.123.mds.34g" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I resolve this problem as follow:

```
var regEx = /class="Name"+ value="(.*?)"/;
newName = result.match(regEx)[1];

var regEx2 = /class="Key"+ value="(.*?)"/;
var key = result.match(regEx2)[1];

Alert(key + ' ' + newName );
```